# ¿Recorrer y guardar datos de un array con laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, array, loops

Tengo el siguiente caso, estoy enviando desde la vista al controlador unos datos de la siguiente forma:

```
<div id="modalities_1">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Modalidad</h3>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        {!!Form::label('Titulo de modalidad','Titulo de modalidad:')!!}
        {!!Form::text('modalities_1[title_modal]',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ingrese el titulo de la modalidad', 'id'=>'modalities_1_title_modal1'])!!}
    </div>



    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        {!!Form::label('Ingrese el precio para esta modalidad','Ingrese el precio para esta modalidad:')!!}
        {!!Form::text('modalities_1[price]',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ingrese el precio para esta modalidad','id'=>'modalities_1_price1'])!!}
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        {!!Form::label('Cantidad','Cantidad de entradas disponibles:')!!}
        {!!Form::text('modalities_1[quantity]',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Cantidad de entradas disponibles','id'=>'modalities_1_quantity1'])!!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        {!!Form::label('Ingrese las condiciones','Ingrese las condiciones pra esta modalidad:')!!}
        {!!Form::text('modalities_1[terms]',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ingrese las condiciones para esta modalidad','id'=>'modalities_1_terms1'])!!}
    </div>
```

El controlador me lo recibe en un array de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es porque es un formulario dinamico en el cual cambio el nombre del array y lo voy aumentando en 1 al final, es decir modalities_1, modalities_2 y asi, la cosa es que como es dinámico puedo borrar alguno de ellos y quedan modalities_1, modalities_3, y asi... no sigue una secuencia como tal. ahora este esta parte del formulario esta asociado a una parte superior, debo guardar este formulario relacioado con otra tabla... el controlador lo tengo asi:

```
          $modalitys = $request->all();


       // dd($modal);
    $event = new Event;
    $event->name_eve = $request->name_eve;
    $event->description = $request->description;
    $event->slug = $request->slug;
    $event->img = $request->img;
    $event->date_event = $request->date_event;
    $event->date_start = $request->date_start;
    $event->date_end = $request->date_end;
    $event->site = $request->site;
    $event->iva = $request->iva;
    $event->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $event->save();

    $id= $event['id'];
 foreach ($modalitys as $key => $value) {

                $title_modal= $modalitys['modalities_1']['title_modal'];
                $price= $modalitys['modalities_1']['price'];
                $quantity= $modalitys['modalities_1']['quantity'];
                $terms= $modalitys['modalities_1']['terms'];
                $modal = [
                            'title_modal'=>$title_modal,            
                            'price'=>$price,
                            'quantity'=>$quantity,
                            'terms'=> $terms,
                            'events_id'=>$id,
                ];


      }
      Modality::create($modal);
```

Los nombres de los campos los genero con jquery, son producto de una clonacion, por lo tanto lo que hago es modificarlos con unas variables, el codigo, asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".add-modal").each(function (el){
  $(this).bind("click",addModal);
 });
});

function addModal(){



 var clickID = parseInt($(this).parent('div').parent('div').attr('id').replace('modalities_',''));

var newID = (clickID+1);


var OldId = 'modalities_'+clickID;
$newModal = $('#modalities_'+clickID).clone(true);

$newModal.attr("id",'modalities_'+newID);
var newAttr = $newModal.attr("id");

$newModal.children("div").children("input").eq(0).attr("id",newAttr+'_'+'title_modal'+newID).val('');
$newModal.children("div").children("input").eq(1).attr("id",newAttr+'_'+'price'+newID).val('');
$newModal.children("div").children("input").eq(2).attr("id",newAttr+'_'+'quantity'+newID).val('');
$newModal.children("div").children("input").eq(3).attr("id",newAttr+'_'+'terms'+newID).val('');
$newModal.children("div").children("input").eq(4).attr("id",newID);
$newDiscount = $newModal.children("div").eq(5).attr("id",newAttr+'_'+'discount_1');
$newDiscount.children("div").children("input").eq(0).attr("id",newAttr+'_'+'discount_1_'+'title_dis1').val('');
$newDiscount.children("div").children("input").eq(1).attr("id",newAttr+'_'+'discount_1_'+'formula1').val('');
$newDiscount.children("div").children("input").eq(2).attr("id",newAttr+'_'+'discount_1_'+'value1').val('');
$newDiscount.children("div").children("a").eq(0).attr("id",newAttr+'_'+'discount_1_'+'add-discount1').val('');

$newModal.children("div").children("input").eq(0).attr("name",newAttr+'[title_modal]');
$newModal.children("div").children("input").eq(1).attr("name",newAttr+'[price]');
$newModal.children("div").children("input").eq(2).attr("name",newAttr+'[quantity]');
$newModal.children("div").children("input").eq(3).attr("name",newAttr+'[terms]');


$newDiscount.children("div").children("input").eq(0).attr("name",newAttr+'[discount_1]'+'[title_dis]');
$newDiscount.children("div").children("input").eq(1).attr("name",newAttr+'[discount_1]'+'[formula]');
$newDiscount.children("div").children("input").eq(2).attr("name",newAttr+'[discount_1]'+'[value]');

var dataId= $newDiscount.children("div").children("a").attr("data_id");


if (dataId == 1) {
 $newDiscount.children("div").children("a").eq(0).off("click",delRowDiscount);
 $newDiscount.children("div").children("a").eq(0).on("click",addDiscount);
}

$newDiscount.children("div").children("a").eq(0).html('<i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Agregar otro descuento');

$newModal.insertAfter($('#modalities_'+clickID));
$('#'+newAttr).children("div[id*="+OldId+"]").remove();

$("#"+clickID).val('- eliminar modalidad').unbind("click",addModal);

$("#"+clickID).bind("click",delRowModal);
}

function delRowModal() {

$(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();

}
```

Lo cual funciona bien con un solo formulario modalities_1 porque lo especifico en en el foreach a la hora de recorrer, la pregunta seria, observando la imagen que subi, existen varios madalities_x los cuales debo guardar cada uno de sus contenidos en una tabla, como podria comprobar esos array y recorrerlos de manera dinamica sin tomar en cuenta el correlativo si no que si existe una clave modalities_x me la tome la recorra y la guarde y asi continue hasta que no existan mas?

Comment: podrias mostrar un var_dump($modalitys) antes del foreach?

Comment: Es el que esta en la imagen, con dd($request->all()); alli esta el detalle de todo lo que recibe el controlador, no esta aplicado el foreach alli. Te sirve ese aquiles?

Comment: ¿cómo se generan los nombres de los campos o formularios `modalities_x`? por favor muestra el código.

Comment: Ya lo coloque Shaz, todo el codigo jquery que genera los nombres. una cosa importante es que el nombre no siempre sera consecutivo como lo explico, porque puedo borrar filas de modalidad y añadir otras y me va aumentando el contador...

Comment: Eso es lo que intentaba entender, porque al hacer tu foreach, no es cierto que todo, lo que va ahi va a tener la key "modalities_x",
Seria ideal si tu Estructura la recibieras de la siguiente forma
array(
"description"=>"algunadescripcion",
"date_event"=>"lafecha",
"modalityces"=>array(
0=>array(
"xcampo"=>"xvalor"
)
)
)

Comment: Aquiles el tema es que tengo que asociar de alguna manera la informacion de cada modalidad a un evento general, la relacion es 1 evento a muchas modalidades, por eso los agrupo en un array de esta manera para posteriormente ser guardado en asociacion al evento principal. Claro un array simple seria mucho mejor, a menos que se separen previamente los array en el mismo controlador...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero intento obtener la forma de saber cuantos `modalities` hay independiente de su identificador numérico, después de eso los recorro cada uno con un `for` accediendo a cada uno y guardando su información en la base de datos:

```
$modalities = array();

foreach ($modalitys as $key => $value) {

    $key_array = explode("_", $key);

    if($key_array[0] == 'modalities'){
        array_push($modalities, $key);
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($modalities); $i++){
    $title_modal = $modalitys[$modalities[$i]]['title_modal'];
    $price= $modalitys[$modalities[$i]]['price'];
    $quantity= $modalitys[$modalities[$i]]['quantity'];
    $terms= $modalitys[$modalities[$i]]['terms'];
    $modal = [
        'title_modal'=>$title_modal,            
        'price'=>$price,
        'quantity'=>$quantity,
        'terms'=> $terms,
        'events_id'=>$id,
    ];

    Modality::create($modal);
}
```

EXPLICACIÓN SOLICITADA:

Cuando haces un `foreach` a `$modalitys` en la variable `$key` se guardan todas las propiedades del objeto `(_token, name_eve, modalities_1, etc, etc)`, luego con el `explode()` estoy convirtiendo el `string` del `$key` en un `array`, quedando algo así `[0=>modalities, 1=>1]` donde el índice 0 viene siendo el nombre como tal y el índice 1 viene siendo el identificador numérico que lo diferencia de los demás, luego le digo que cuando el índice 0 (osea el nombre) sea igual a `modalities` es por que es un `array` que hay que recorrer y en caso de que se cumpla la condición agrego a la variable `$modalities` cada uno de los identificadores numéricos que correspondan quedando algo así `$modalities = array(1, 2, 3.....n);`

Comment: Oye Camilo me gusto ese codigo, algo asi tambien habia pensado pero no sabia como plantearlo, ahora la cosa es que me esta comenzando con modalities_0, entonces me dice que "Undefined index: modalities_0"  asumo que es por que la expr 1 del for comienza en 0 y alli es que empieza, probe que comenzara en 1, pero hace algo curioso, me guarda el modalities_1 la cantidad de modalities_x que hayan, entonces no me funciona asi, debe haber una manera de tomar los modalities que se hayan generado no crees?

Comment: No te entendí muy bien, el indice 0 si es por que la variable $i estaba en cero, ya la cambié a 1 en la respuesta, pero lo otro no te alcanzo a entender bien

Comment: Osea lo que quiero decir es que colocando el $i = 1 en la expresion, relice la prueba, pero no me guarda los datos de cada uno de los formularios dinamicos que va generando, porque modalities_1 es un formulario, modalities_2 otro, y modalities_4 es otro, utilice este metodo con la $i = 1 y lo que hizo es guardar 3 veces los datos de modalities1, no me guardo los datos de cada uno de los modalities... no se si me explico...

Comment: te acabé de editar la respuesta con otra forma, me avisas si te funciona !!

Comment: Oye dos problemas, hice la prueba guardando solo dos modalities, y me guarda 7 registros 4 veces la primera y tres veces la segunda en un orden raro, primero guarda dos veces la primera, y despues de manera impar, asi guarda la segunda, despues la primera, despues la segunda hasta llegar 7 veces... que hace el explode?

Comment: y cuando probe generando modalities_1, modalities_2 y modalities_4 y guardando me guardaba las dos primera, pero se paraba porque pedia modalities_3, asumo que es por el autoincrement que busca el numero que viene...

Comment: Si, por eso quité el incrementable y mejor lo que hice fue guardar en un array los nombres completos, es extraño lo que te pasa, el explode convierte un string a array, voy a revisar otra vez el codigo

Comment: Ahora bien camilo, hay alguna manera de tomar solo el numero que esta despues del _, almacerlos todos en un array en la forma sencilla y luego recorrer ese array y utilizar esos numeros para dar forma a modalities_x la x seria cada numero de esos? creo que asi, si funcionaria... tienes una idea?

Comment: Te acabe de editar la respuesta en la línea del for, claro que se puede !! intenta con lo que acabé de editar si no funciona te muestro como se haría tu idea

Comment: Listo Camilo, tienes razón!! Estaba cometiendo un error, tenia el ciclo for dentro del foreach!! Lo siento, agradecido por la paciencia y el apoyo!

Comment: Camilo disculpa, una consulta, podrias explicarme como funciona el $key_array y el condicional?? Entiendo que alli es donde captura la clave, modalities_x y las actualiza en el array $modalities pero no entiendo como funciona je

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta con la explicación que me solicitaste, espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro ! Saludos !